# Diff tool to align shuffled lines

Tags: diff, text-files

Suppose I have two documents that are identical except the lines are shuffled. Is there a tool that can show me which lines in document A correspond to which lines on document B by drawing lines to connect them (kinda like [Cairo](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/smith+jahr.lrec00.pdf) does for machine translation word alignments)?

What if the files have some level of differing lines (I don't want to figure out which lines are similar to each other -- if there isn't an exact match for a line, then that line has no match.)

Note: I am not looking to sort the files and compare them, rather I am looking to get a visualization of how far out of order the files are relative to each other, and which particular regions tend to move together, and which tend to be shuffled.

Comment: Windiff will show you the line in the left file it thinks the line in the right file came from, but it's often mistaken when lines are the same (e.g. a line with just a } in a cc file).

Comment: jeffamaphone, I gave it a try under Wine, and it looks like it does the right thing. Can you submit your answer as an answer rather than as a comment, so that you'll be eligible for the bounty? Do you know of similar software for Linux?

Comment: @jeffamaphone - see Ken's comment... @Ken - FYI if you prefix a user's name with an `@` when you reply to a comment, they'll get notified by the system (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windiff will show you the line in the left file it thinks the line in the right file came from, but it's often mistaken when lines are the same (e.g. a line with just a } in a cc file).

Comment: I gave it a try under Wine, and it looks like it does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [psame](http://search.cpan.org/~kim/Text-Same-0.07/bin/psame) in a google search which (at least algorithmically) does the same thing.